# Dibujar burbuja de chat

Tags: java, java-swing

encontre este codigo en la pagina stackOverflow en ingles.

```
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
 final Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;

 RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
 graphics2D.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
 graphics2D.setPaint(new Color(80, 150, 180));

 int width = getWidth();
 int height = getHeight();

 GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();

 path.moveTo(5, 10);
 path.curveTo(5, 10, 7, 5, 0, 0);
 path.curveTo(0, 0, 12, 0, 12, 5);
 path.curveTo(12, 5, 12, 0, 20, 0);
 path.lineTo(width - 10, 0);
 path.curveTo(width - 10, 0, width, 0, width, 10);
 path.lineTo(width, height - 10);
 path.curveTo(width, height - 10, width, height, width - 10, height);
 path.lineTo(15, height);
 path.curveTo(15, height, 5, height, 5, height - 10);
 path.lineTo(5, 15);
 path.closePath();
 graphics2D.fill(path);
}
```

El codigo anterior crea una burbuja como esta.

https://postimg.org/image/723zyaxcf/

Mi pregunta es como hacer el mismo pero de la siguiente forma.

https://postimg.org/image/lthn9exhd/

De manera que la flecha que apunta, quede hacia abajo..

Gracias y disculpen mi ignorancia

Comment: David y qué ha intentado ? Sabe cómo funciona `GeneralPath` ?

Answer (score 0):

La clase `GeneralPath` utiliza **2** métodos para sus dibujos:

1. `lineTo(x,y)` Se mueve en línea recta teniendo en cuenta su posición
2. `curveTo(x1,y1,xmedio,ymedio,xfinal,yfinal)` Va generando una curva teniendo en cuenta las tres coordenadas dadas.

El siguiente código genera una forma similar a la que ud requiere:

```
int width = 150;
int height = 50;

// starting point
int x = 20;
int y = 20;

path.moveTo(x,y);

// inicio imágen
path.curveTo(x, y, x + 2, y - 2, x + 4, y - 4);
path.lineTo(width-4, y-4);
path.curveTo(width-4, y-4,width+2, y, width, y+4);
path.lineTo(width, height-4);
path.curveTo(width, height-4, width+2, height, width+4, height+4);
path.curveTo(width+4, height+4, width, height, width-4, height-4);
path.curveTo(width-4, height-2, width-6, height+2, width-8, height);
path.lineTo(x+4, height);
path.curveTo(x+4, height, x-2, height-2, x, height-4);
path.lineTo(x, y);
```

La siguiente imagen tiene varias ventanas; cada ventana representa una línea de código a partir del primer **path.curveTo..**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]